# Bitbucket pipeline SFTP connection doesn't open host SFTP prompt

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, sftp, bitbucket-pipelines

Having the following bitbucket-pipeline.yml:

```
pipelines: 
 default: 
  - step: 
   name: deploy to production 
   script: 
    - sftp -oPort=PPPP pi@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
    - cd /home/username/webserver
    - put -r nameOfTheBuildFolder build/ - exit
```

I can see that  the sftp command is being executed, but the result is just logging:

"Connected to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"

But it's not opening a sftp prompt.

Is there a way to actually browse and do command on the sftp prompt? Or is there a command to connect to the sftp prompt?

I opened also a ticket at the community of atlassion: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/SFTP-connection-doesn-t-open-host-SFTP-prompt/qaq-p/805328#M27869

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i've found the following command that allows you to copy files via SSH on a secure and fast way:

scp nameOfTheBuildFolder build/